# Rails - Reference Table for Lookups

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to efficiently implement a table, array, list, etc in Rails for reference and lookup purposes. For example, let's say I have a list of 'approved' colors to be used in the application. Where should I put this data and how best to access it? (Table in DB, Global Constant, CSV file?)

Approved List Data: "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"

Comment: This is totally dependent on your implementation. Without more details, your question is impossible to answer intelligently.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you use it. Typically I create an application helper that I can use to call it and store them as an array there. Then it would be something like `"blue".include?(approved_colors)`

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly just a static list that doesn't need to changed, I'd create a constant. Where to do this depends on what you're using it for.

```
APPROVED_LIST = [
  'Blue',
  'Green',
  'Red'
].freeze
```

If it's model specific, I'd throw it in that model, otherwise ApplicationHelper isn't a bad place.

If you're needing to *use* these colors somehow (maybe for CSS?) then a different workflow might be necessary.